# Count IF multiple criteria/data types match

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to generate a report to list the number of Cities/Towns that don't meet a certain criteria so on Sheet 2 I have an alphabetical list of all the cities/towns.

I want to do a look up/count if function to state if A2(Sheet 2) can be found anywhere in Column D on Sheet 1 then count it if the date in column L (sheet 1) matches the date in Cell $E$1 (sheet 2) and Column A in Sheet 1 is greater than zero.

I originally done this formula but it is returning an error.

> =COUNTIFS(PickData!D:D,Sheet1!A2,PickData!L:L,Sheet1!$E$1,PickData!A:A,PickData!A:A>0)

Is there any other formulas that I'm currently not thinking of? Or is it possible to do this via VBA and it returns the value in to column B either True if it matches or False if it doesn't?

Thanks
Al

Comment: It's not returning an error but it's not returning a value of the count if it matches the criteria

Comment: How do you mean @pnuts the sheet reference being the wrong way round? I've tried to use the formula in the answer below?

Comment: Sheet1 is pickdata sorry I realise what I had done with the formula! Additionally when I remove the column A greater than zero it gives me a value!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your previous formula is in the final criteria.  Update to:

```
=COUNTIFS(PickData!D:D,Sheet1!A2,PickData!L:L,Sheet1!E2,PickData!A:A,">0")
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't return a value of 1 when I done the slight change :-/

Comment: It should return the amount of rows that fit these criteria, not the value of 1.  When do you expect it to return the value of 1?  What did it return?

Comment: If I purposely setup one line to match the criteria Id expect 1 however all cities/towns are showing zero even though multiple match the criteria.

Comment: Your explanation was unclear. It sounds like you are trying to copy the formula down in each row and list either 1 or zero for the row if this data exists in the other sheet.  Your formula was always looking at column E in sheet 1.  Try the proposed edit and you should at least get positive values.

Comment: I think I've figured a way to do this! It couldn't do the greater than blank formula so I added a column into pick data which is a simple if greater than blank true else false! Now my count if formula looks for the true statement and returns the value.